# Pandas: Sum current and following cell in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Python code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas_datareader import data as wb

stock='3988.HK'

df = wb.DataReader(stock,data_source='yahoo',start='2018-07-01')

rsi_period = 14

chg = df['Close'].diff(1)

gain = chg.mask(chg<0,0)
df['Gain'] = gain

loss = chg.mask(chg>0,0)
df['Loss'] = loss

avg_gain = gain.ewm(com = rsi_period-1,min_periods=rsi_period).mean()
avg_loss = loss.ewm(com = rsi_period-1,min_periods=rsi_period).mean()

df['Avg Gain'] = avg_gain
df['Avg Loss'] = avg_loss

rs = abs(avg_gain/avg_loss)

rsi = 100-(100/(1+rs))

df['RSI'] = rsi

df.reset_index(inplace=True)

df
```

Output:

```
        Date    High    Low     Open    Close   Volume  Adj Close   Gain    Loss    Avg Gain    Avg Loss    RSI
0   2018-07-03  3.87    3.76    3.83    3.84    684899302.0 3.629538    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   2018-07-04  3.91    3.84    3.86    3.86    460325574.0 3.648442    0.02    0.00    NaN NaN NaN
2   2018-07-05  3.70    3.62    3.68    3.68    292810499.0 3.680000    0.00    -0.18   NaN NaN NaN
3   2018-07-06  3.72    3.61    3.69    3.67    343653088.0 3.670000    0.00    -0.01   NaN NaN NaN
4   2018-07-09  3.75    3.68    3.70    3.69    424596186.0 3.690000    0.02    0.00    NaN NaN NaN
5   2018-07-10  3.74    3.70    3.71    3.71    327048051.0 3.710000    0.02    0.00    NaN NaN NaN
6   2018-07-11  3.65    3.61    3.63    3.64    371355401.0 3.640000    0.00    -0.07   NaN NaN NaN
7   2018-07-12  3.69    3.63    3.66    3.66    309888328.0 3.660000    0.02    0.00    NaN NaN NaN
8   2018-07-13  3.69    3.62    3.69    3.63    261928758.0 3.630000    0.00    -0.03   NaN NaN NaN
9   2018-07-16  3.63    3.57    3.61    3.62    306970074.0 3.620000    0.00    -0.01   NaN NaN NaN
10  2018-07-17  3.62    3.56    3.62    3.58    310294921.0 3.580000    0.00    -0.04   NaN NaN NaN
11  2018-07-18  3.61    3.55    3.58    3.58    334592695.0 3.580000    0.00    0.00    NaN NaN NaN
12  2018-07-19  3.61    3.56    3.61    3.56    211984563.0 3.560000    0.00    -0.02   NaN NaN NaN
13  2018-07-20  3.64    3.52    3.57    3.61    347506394.0 3.610000    0.05    0.00    NaN NaN NaN
14  2018-07-23  3.65    3.57    3.59    3.62    313125328.0 3.620000    0.01    0.00    0.010594    -0.021042   33.487100
15  2018-07-24  3.71    3.60    3.60    3.68    367627204.0 3.680000    0.06    0.00    0.015854    -0.018802   45.745967
16  2018-07-25  3.73    3.68    3.72    3.69    270460990.0 3.690000    0.01    0.00    0.015252    -0.016868   47.483263
17  2018-07-26  3.73    3.66    3.72    3.69    234388072.0 3.690000    0.00    0.00    0.013731    -0.015186   47.483263
18  2018-07-27  3.70    3.66    3.68    3.69    190039532.0 3.690000    0.00    0.00    0.012399    -0.013713   47.483263
19  2018-07-30  3.72    3.67    3.68    3.70    163971848.0 3.700000    0.01    0.00    0.012172    -0.012417   49.502851
20  2018-07-31  3.70    3.66    3.67    3.68    168486023.0 3.680000    0.00    -0.02   0.011047    -0.013118   45.716244
21  2018-08-01  3.72    3.66    3.71    3.68    199801191.0 3.680000    0.00    0.00    0.010047    -0.011930   45.716244
22  2018-08-02  3.68    3.59    3.66    3.61    307920738.0 3.610000    0.00    -0.07   0.009155    -0.017088   34.884632
23  2018-08-03  3.62    3.57    3.59    3.61    184816985.0 3.610000    0.00    0.00    0.008356    -0.015596   34.884632
24  2018-08-06  3.66    3.60    3.62    3.61    189696153.0 3.610000    0.00    0.00    0.007637    -0.014256   34.884632
25  2018-08-07  3.66    3.61    3.63    3.65    216157642.0 3.650000    0.04    0.00    0.010379    -0.013048   44.302922
26  2018-08-08  3.66    3.61    3.65    3.63    215365540.0 3.630000    0.00    -0.02   0.009511    -0.013629   41.101805
27  2018-08-09  3.66    3.59    3.59    3.65    230275455.0 3.650000    0.02    0.00    0.010378    -0.012504   45.353992
28  2018-08-10  3.66    3.60    3.65    3.62    219157328.0 3.620000    0.00    -0.03   0.009530    -0.013933   40.617049
29  2018-08-13  3.59    3.54    3.58    3.56    270620120.0 3.560000    0.00    -0.06   0.008759    -0.017658   33.158019
```

In this case, i want to create a new column 'max close within 14 trade days'.
'max close within 14 trade days' = Maximum 'close' within next 14 days.
For example,
in row 0, the data range should be from row 1 to row 15,
'max close within 14 trade days' = 3.86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# convert to date time
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# calculate max for 14 days
df['max_close_within_14_trade_days'] = df['Date'].map(df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='14D')])['Close'].max())

# fill missing values by previous value
df['max_close_within_14_trade_days'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)

    Date    High    Low    Open  Close    max_close_within_14_trade_days
0   0   2018-07-03  3.87    3.76    3.83    3.86
1   1   2018-07-04  3.91    3.84    3.86    3.86
2   2   2018-07-05  3.70    3.62    3.68    3.86
3   3   2018-07-06  3.72    3.61    3.69    3.86
4   4   2018-07-09  3.75    3.68    3.70    3.86
```

Other solution:

```
df['max_close_within_14_trade_days'] = [df.loc[x+1:x+14,'Close'].max() for x in range(0, df.shape[0])]
```

Comment: Thanks YOLO
i implied your code, i sill have some problems:
1. is it possible to using index(e.g. 0,1,2,3,4) rather than Date?
As my data is generated by "trade day" that mean Saturday and Sunday did not include in the data. 
2. the result is not quite right. (Range = next 14 rows,not include current row).
In row 1, the range should be from row 2 to row 15, max=3.71.
In row 2, the range should be from row 3 to row 16, max=3.71.

Comment: @JonathanTong what about this: `df['max_close_within_14_trade_days'] = [df.loc[x+1:x+14,'Close'].max() for x in range(0, df.shape[0])]`

Comment: Thank you very much. You make my day!!